# Select from a table with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I have 3 tables:

1. Person
2. Groups
3. PersonsGroups

I need to select all persons when they are in the group from a list 
(list from few groups)

I tried to select like this:

```
var tdd = GS.PersonsGroups.Include("Person")
            .Where(r => s.Contains(r.GroupID.Value))
            .Select(c => c.Person);
```

But it is not `Person` is it `PersonGroup` and I don't have all `Person` prop

What is the right way to get it?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Do you have a `Groups` navigation property on your `Person` entity?

Comment: Group no but PersonGroups yes

Comment: So why not just `GS.Persons.Where(p => s.Contains(p.Groups.ID))`?

Comment: @DavidG the Groups dosnt have  ID

Comment: What is the primary key for `Group` then?

Comment: You could pre-empt a lot of questions by showing the class details.

Comment: Your query looks correct, there must be something wrong with your navigation properties so you'll have to link the classes of your models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct, you are seeking for something like this

```
List<int> groupIds = ...;
var query = db.Persons
    .Where(p => p.PersonGroups.Any(pg => groupIds.Contains(pg.GroupID.Value));
```